# If I roll 5 casino dice at the same time, does the order in which I read the results matter?

Tags: random, dice, algorithmic-randomness

If I want to get a **perfectly random** sequence of numbers in range 1 to 6, possibly very long, and roll 5 casino dice at the same time, does the order in which I read the numbers from individual dice after each roll, matter?

Repeatedly rolling just one dice and writing down each result would be one possibility to get a perfectly random sequence, but it takes a rather long time. So to speed things up I am going to use 5 dice at the same time, to get 5 random numbers for each roll.

So the question is: From the randomness theory point of view, does the order, in which I write down the 5 numbers after each roll, matter?

Suppose my 5 casino dice have different colors: red, yellow, green, blue, pink. When I roll 5 dice, they are shuffled and there the order different colors are lying on the table after each roll is random.

Does it matter for the "quality of randomness" of my sequence if I write down dice numbers always as:

1. Roll 5 dice at the same time
2. Write down 5 numbers always IN THAT ORDER:
   red    -> 1st number,
   yellow -> 2nd number,
   green  -> 3rd number,
   blue   -> 4th number,
   pink   -> 5th number.
3. Repeat from step 1

Or if I write down the number from step 2 as:
 yellow, green, pink, red, blue.
and at the next roll as
 pink, red, green, yellow, blue.
and so on... (the way the lie on the table from left to right)

So does it matter, whether each dice keeps its "fixed position" in the row of five across different rolls?

Answer (score 1):

Your method with the coloured dices creates random sequences

In fact, any method of choosing the order of the five dices which is determined **before** the outcome of the dices is valid to create a iid sequence.
You could (for example) choose a new order of colours after every throw and the result would still be iid.

If the order of the five dices depend on the outcome of the dices you would introduce autocorrelation.

Comment: Thanks, initially that was my gut feeling, too. On second thought: if it really does not matter, then every time I get, say, 4,6,3,1,5 and there's no rule, I am free to write it down as 1,3,4,5,6 always choosing ascending order. But then the natural question arises: If a presumably "perfectly random" sequence is sorted in group of fives, is it really truly random? I think this is contradictory to the common sense of randomness, if one just looks at it and immediately spots repeating patterns, such as all numbers being sorted in groups of five. So I somehow doubt the answer, it would not matter

Comment: it is a difference if you first look at all 5 dices and then pick an order or if you pick an order and then look at the dices. 
It also depends on what you want to do with the result: would it matter if you  would order the result?

Comment: As I said, my goal was to have a 100% mathematically correct formal process description, how to generate a "perfectly random" endless sequence of numbers in range 1 to 6 by rolling 5 "perfect" casino dice at the same time. Just this. The process description "the order how to write down 5 numbers of each roll does not matter" does not seem correct, in my opinion. I tried to explain why. What you said afterwards, it's kindof “understood”, that I am not allowed to look at the numbers contradicts to the formal description “order does not matter”. So it DOES matter, then?

Comment: Ok I understand now, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the dice don’t necessarily have to be colored, as long as I predetermine the reading order before the outcome of each roll. This could as well be just one simple rule: “when all 5 dice come to rest, I will always read the numbers from left to right, as they lie on the table in front of me”. This is mathematically just as good as any other rule involving colors or anything else, right?

Comment: yeah, you are right